# How to include ProxyCommand to JGit SshClient

Tags: java, http-proxy, jgit

I'm trying to implement a way in java to do SCP operations on a remote server via java through an http-proxy. To do that, I use JGit (as suggested by the apache mina developer due to the implementation of a proxy function). To get to the remote host, I need a proxy tunnel, which I already use.
When I'm trying to do scp that way via "ProxyCommand" in a shell it works as intended:

Now I need to find a way to give JGit a ProxyCommand (Proxy is running locally on port 7084):

```
proxytunnel -p localhost:7084 -d host_ip:22 -v
```

I already tried adding it to the ".ssh/config" file like this:

```
Host host_ip
  HostName host_ip
  ProxyCommand proxytunnel -p localhost:7084 -d host_ip -v
```

but it seems like JGit ignores that.

here is my code for more context:

```
    JGitSshClient client = (JGitSshClient) ClientBuilder.builder().factory(JGitSshClient::new).build(); 
            
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("==================Starten client==================");
    client.start();

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("==================Proxy einbinden==================");
    client.setProxyDatabase(remote -> new ProxyData(new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(proxyHost, proxyPort)), proxyUser, proxyPass));

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("==================Verbindung==================");


    HostConfigEntry host = new HostConfigEntry("", hostname, 22, username);        

    try (ClientSession session = client.connect(host).verify().getSession()){ 

        //SCP Operations

    }
```

does anyone else have an idea?